# What is a word or phrase for an attitude that focuses on improving the future/favours delayed gratification?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I wish to express within a word or two an attitude or way of living that sacrifices for the foreseeable future and strives to reap better long-term rewards at the expense of short(er)-term effort. This attitude emphasises purposeful living, looking towards the future and (sort-of) favours delayed gratification. I guess the *biggest* emphasis is one of improving, investing in and preparing for the future, not the sacrificial part. I do not mind single word or phrase suggestions, I'm trying to get a best fit.

Intended sentence: "It is also of interesting sociological note that what X interprets as the best attitude towards living is one of purposeful creativity and ..." I am unsure whether or not I will retain the "purposeful creativity" if I get better words for the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **prudence**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prudent) as

> Acting with or showing care and thought for the future.

Note that this word doesn't carry the connotations of any sort of sacrifice but naming a sacrifice as prudence is alright.

Another option similar to *prudence* in use is **far-sighted**ness, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/far-sighted) as

> Showing a prudent awareness of future possibilities.

Comment: Hmm, I think prudent leans a bit too much towards 'careful' ? I got foresight off of your far-sightedness, though. Thanks.